# Building a Macro to Download Data off a Website into Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I would like to build a macro in Excel using VBA to download historical data off the following website:

http://quickstats.nass.usda.gov/results/320F1D82-1064-30F1-809E-F77E509EC508

I first create a command button as usual. I then thought this may be able to be easily solved using a macro recorder. However when I select Data -> Get External Data -> From Web and then type in the above address I am unable to select the table as a whole as the data.

So, I am unsure how to do this task otherwise but I feel there may be some standard code somewhere, which I have been unable to find, in order to complete the task.

I feel that this task is useful to many people, as scripts to download data off websites can be used in a variety of places.

Comment: The page you linked has a link to resources for Developers. Did you check that out?

Comment: Yes, I didn't want to use their API and I would rather do it myself in VBA as the concept of downloading data from a website is more generally applicable

Comment: I wish that downvoters would also leave a comment explaining why. With bare downvotes you're often left scratchin' the noggin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways of getting data from a website using VBA. You can navigate to it using an InternetExplorer object and parse the HTML once you're there. You can also craft HTTP requests using MSXML2.XMLHTTP. Excel in particular has a number of data-link options that can do this.

However, here I'd use the tools that the UDSA have ever-so-kindly provided for you, and do it in one line:

```
Workbooks.Open ("http://quickstats.nass.usda.gov/data/spreadsheet/4C43034A-0EAA-3171-B4FC-84CC95FC6E0C.csv")
```

EDIT: In response to Sandstone's question below, here's some code to copy data from that workbook into your existing one.

```
Dim thisWb, downloadWb As Workbook
Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook

Set downloadWb = Workbooks.Open("http://quickstats.nass.usda.gov/data/spreadsheet/4C43034A-0EAA-3171-B4FC-84CC95FC6E0C.csv")

downloadWb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:U2613").Copy Destination:=thisWb.Worksheets(1).Range("A2")

downloadWb.Close
```

Of course, you'll want to change the ranges and so on to match the data you need.

Comment: I like this but I am currently trying to work out how modify this to get the data into the sheet where the command button is in Excel (ie changing Workbooks. to something else)

Comment: @sandstone There are a number of ways you could do this. If you just want to take all the data then perhaps the easiest way is to copy all the data from a sheet in the downloaded workbook into one in your main workbook. I've updated the answer with some sample code for this.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of trying to download a dynamic table, you can try downloading the table from the "printable" version of the table instead. The URL for the printable table was;

> Blockquote http://quickstats.nass.usda.gov/results/320F1D82-1064-30F1-809E-F77E509EC508

and with VBA;

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://quickstats.nass.usda.gov/data/printable/4C43034A-0EAA-3171-B4FC-84CC95FC6E0C" _
    , Destination:=Range("$F$10"))
```

I could download the table with a macro.

Comment: This doesnt work for me...Compile error: Expected End With

Answer (score 0):

It's because what looks like a table is in fact a stack of lots of single-line tables, generated dynamically (you can see that when you scroll down), buried in >= 8 levels of `<div>`.

Use e.g. Firefox and "Inspect element" to see the page structure.

So this page is a particularly bad example for the task you want to do.

Comment: 1) Are you suggesting that my original thought process would work in other instances? 2) Do you know a way to overcome the problem with this particular page?

Comment: 1) In principle, yes. Although I did some playing around with a few Wikipedia pages containing tables, and I have the feeling that `QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;...` works only for rather simple pages. 2) Yes... click "Spreadsheet" to get a csv of the whole table. Which you aren't going to get by reading from the page, I think, because only the parts requested by the browser are generated (dynamically).