# Creating a Macro to Index Data from Government Website

Tags: database, vba, excel

[image]

I provide the link here: http://quickstats.nass.usda.gov/results/320F1D82-1064-30F1-809E-F77E509EC508. I would like to learn how to perform this task using a macro/script in Excel VBA. The problems which I have been unable to overcome myself are:

1) Not all the weeks in the year are represented in the data. I am not sure how to sort the data by particular week, not sure what command I would need.

2) Is is possible to the Excel function VLOOKUP in my vba script in order to select all the distinct values, say Week14 or Week15, before performing the calculation for each week? If so, how is it incorporated? My idea was to just perform a VLOOKUP in the macro to search for the five different crop conditions.

My first question on this topic was about how to download the information off the website, see [Building a Macro to Download Data off a Website into Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167545/building-a-macro-to-download-data-off-a-website-into-excel). I suggest that this is the first button, "download", and then there should be a second button to sort the data called "sort".

CommandButton_1 is for download data, see linked question.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim thisWb, downloadWb As Workbook
Set thisWb = ActiveWorkbook

Set downloadWb = Workbooks.Open("http://quickstats.nass.usda.gov/data/spreadsheet/4C43034A-0EAA-3171-B4FC-84CC95FC6E0C.csv")

downloadWb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:U2613").Copy Destination:=thisWb.Worksheets(3).Range("A8")

downloadWb.Close

End Sub
```

This works very well. Now the second button (Sort Data) it was suggested below that

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Public Function WeekTotal(Condition As String, Table As Range) As Integer
Dim rRow As Range
Dim xVal As Integer

xVal = 0
For Each rRow In Table.Rows
        If InStr(LCase(rRow.Cells(1, 10).Value), "very") > 0 And LCase(Condition) = "poor" Then
            'skip if row includes 'very', but the condition is 'poor' and not 'very poor'
        ElseIf InStr(LCase(rRow.Cells(1, 10).Value), LCase(Condition)) > 0 Then
            xVal = xVal + rRow.Cells(1, 13).Value
        End If
Next rRow

WeekTotal = xVal

End Function

End Sub
```

This does not seem to work. Here is a picture, slightly altered width of columns, of what I am trying to deal with.

[image]

Comment: Vlookup is  a function to reurn values from distinct table. I dont think that is what you wish. Tell us about your calculation.

Comment: Extract the grade from data item and multiply it by the value?

Comment: If it's as simple as that, why not just add an additional column, do a VLOOKUP on the value that corresponds to "Excellent," for example, and then in a new worksheet, use SUMIF?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think I can see why someone might. Some things to consider: 
1: 'a macro to create a formula'  means a macro that actually *creates* a brand new formula each time it is ran. I think you want a custom formula written in VBA?
2: Your #2 asks how you `select` all the `distinct values` using `VLOOKUP`. Formulas cannot select cells, I think you actually want to do... something ...with them. sum them up? Count them? Not 100% sure. 
3: I'm not sure which `distinct values` you are referring too.

Comment: @sandstone Downvotes usually mean there was little or no research effort or the question is unclear.

Comment: @sandstone did any of the answers below help?

Comment: How do you determine a distinct value per week? Just thinking you could cut down on VBA and use a conditional format that highlights the row perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, a macro is over-complicating a simple problem.

1. Simply add a new column with a `VLOOKUP` on the value that corresponds to your rating. To accomplish this, you will need a reference range that can provide such a value. (See screenshot 1).
2. In a new worksheet, list your weeks, and use `SUMIF` to calculate the total of the values in your `vlookup` column for each corresponding week. (See screenshot 2).

If you need to do a more sophisticated calculation, then provide additional detail and I'll modify this answer to help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- `I45` = "Excellent"
- `J2:J36` is the Data Item column
- `M2:M36` is the Value column

`=SUM(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(I45,$J$2:$J$36)),0,$M$2:$M$36))`

Returns: `14`

This is an array formula, so you have to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter, not just Enter. (You will know you did it correctly because it will look like this in the formula bar: `{=SUM(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(I45,$J$2:$J$36)),0,$M$2:$M$36))}`

It automatically adds `{` and `}` when you press Ctrl+Shift+Enter - you do not type them in.

What this formula does:

`Search("Excellent", $J$2)` would look for the string "Excellent" in `J2` and return the position it found the string or an error if it did not find the string. We don't care about the actual value - we just want to know if it throws an error or not. We turn this into an array by using `$J$2:$J$36`. You can't see it, but what this actually does is return an array of values that might look like this :

`{44;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;44;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;44;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;44;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;44;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;44;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;44;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!}`

By using `ISERROR(SEARCH("Excellent", $J$2:$J$36))` we change that internal array into this:

`{FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE}`

If it fails to find "Excellent", `ISERROR` will be `TRUE`, so we want to find the value for all the `FALSE` values in this array. We do this using `IF`. If the `SEARCH` is an error, 0, else give us the value another array - `$M$2:$M$36` (the value column).

`=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Excellent", $J$2:$J$36)), 0,$M$2:$M$36)`

This gives us the following: 
`{2;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;0;2;0;0;0;0}`

Since your sample data had 2 for excellent for each week.

Finally we add `SUM()` around it all to sum up the values.

`=SUM(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Excellent", $J$2:$J$36)), 0,$M$2:$M$36))`

Again, since this is an array formula, if you just hit enter with this formula, it will return `0`, but if you hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter it will give you the correct result of `14`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use VBA, simply as practice, here is how you could use a custom formula.

To use this function you would type the following into a cell:

`=WeekTotal("Excellent",$A$2:$M$36)`

VBA code:

```
Public Function WeekTotal(Condition As String, Table As Range) As Integer
Dim rRow As Range
Dim xVal As Integer

xVal = 0
For Each rRow In Table.Rows
        If InStr(LCase(rRow.Cells(1, 10).Value), "very") > 0 And LCase(Condition) = "poor" Then
            'skip if row includes 'very', but the condition is 'poor' and not 'very poor'
        ElseIf InStr(LCase(rRow.Cells(1, 10).Value), LCase(Condition)) > 0 Then
            xVal = xVal + rRow.Cells(1, 13).Value
        End If
Next rRow

WeekTotal = xVal

End Function
```